# Why is my Villager Breeder not working. Minecraft 1.16.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I created my own villager breeder. It runs on 1.16.4, and it ran perfectly. It produced about 9 villagers, then stopped. There are 4 beds that the villagers can see. I feed them tons of bread. I traded with them to raise my reputation. They aren't making any heart particles either. Nothing happened between the production to now, except me trying to fix it. I don't think that the other 2 open beds are claimed. They always sleep in their beds at night too.

#### Screenshots

[image: Villager Breeder][image: Villager Breeder]

Comment: If this is your own model, could you add a screenshot or two? Or is there a youtube video you could link to?

Comment: This is my own model, and I'll add some screenshots

Comment: Have you moved the newly produced villagers permanently more than 100 blocks away so they can't link back to the beds? As you are in creative already, can you just place down an additional 10 beds on the ground and see if it starts to work again - then you know it's an issue with beds being taken by villagers somewhere.